# How do I restart gunicorn hup , i dont know masterpid or location of PID file

Tags: django, gunicorn

I want to restart a Django server which is running using gunicorn.

I know how to use gunicorn in my system. But now I need to restart a remote server which is not set up by me.

I don't know `masterpid` to restart the server how can I get the masterPID.

Usually I `HUP` gunicorn with `sudo kill -s HUP masterpid`.

I tried with `ps aux|grep gunicorn`

and I did not find the `gunicorn.pid` file anywhere.

How can I get the `masterpid`?

Answer (score 19):

the one liner below, gets the job perfectly done:

```
kill -HUP `ps -C gunicorn fch -o pid | head -n 1`
```

#### Explanation

`ps -C gunicorn` only lists the processes with `gunicorn` command, i.e., workers and **master** process. Workers are children of **master** as can be seen using `ps -C gunicorn fc -o ppid,pid,cmd`. We only need the pid of the **master**, therefore `h` flag is used to remove the first line which is PID text. Note that, `f` flag assures that `master` is printed above workers.

The correct procedure is to send `HUP` signal only to the **master**. In this way `gunicorn` is gracefully restarted, *only the workers, not master, are recreated*.

Comment: Awesome. works perfectly.

Answer (score 14):

You can run gunicorn with option '-p', so you can get the pid of the master process from the pid file.
For example:

```
gunicorn -p app.pid your_app.wsgi.app
```

You can get the pid of the master by:

```
cat app.pid
```

Answer (score 4):

This should also work to restart gunicorn:

```
ps aux |grep gunicorn |grep yourapp | awk '{ print $2 }' |xargs kill -HUP
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** 
 Go to /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service and open file
 add bellow line

```
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn/gunicorn.pid  
--pid /run/gunicorn/gunicorn.pid
```

Example:

```
[Service]
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn/gunicorn.pid
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/django_project
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --pid /run/gunicorn/gunicorn.pid --name=django_project.....
User=django
Group=django
```

**Step 2:** 
  Go to /etc/tmpfiles.d/ and create new file gunicorn.conf if not exist

add Bellow line

```
d /run/gunicorn 0755 django django -
```

where django = user and group name

**Step 3:**
Reboot your server or `/etc/init.d/gunicorn restart` to restart gunicorn to take effect

**your pid file location is /run/gunicorn/gunicorn.pid check now..**

Answer (score 2):

Building on krizex's answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361529/12654535), when your master `pid` is stored in a file, you can gracefully reload your app in one command like this

```
$ cat app.pid |xargs kill -HUP
```

I would have liked to comment on the answer itself but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly improved version if you have multiple gunicorn master processes running on the same server:

```
ps -C gunicorn --no-headers -o ppid,pid | awk '$1=="1" {print $2}' | while read pid; do sudo kill -s HUP $pid; done
```